Minimal example of new function in Qutebrowser
General overview
I am trying to create a function I can call from Qutebrowser with ex mode (the commands starting with :).
But I can’t find a way to do it.
What I did
In my config.py, I added the following lines:
# Function deffinition
def example_function():
    print("The function started")

# Link the python function to ex-mode function
c.aliases['example-command'] = example_function

In this case, c.aliases take just the output of example_function(), and does not run example_function() each time I call it.
The question
How to create a new function in Qutebrowser and assign it to an ex command or a keybinding ?
